# How to override module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/searchlist.phtml

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have create a custom theme. and I want to override searchlist file.

```
 vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/searchlist.phtml
```

I move it in

```
public_html/app/design/frontend/themevendor/theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/
```

But its render output from vendor. I am new in magento2 so can you suggest me where am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your file to your custom theme

> public_html/app/design/frontend/../../Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/searchlist.phtml

And not need to deploy your custom theme. only run below command

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 1):

in magento2 we can override the templates.
for that we have to create directory structure like this:
**app/design/frontend/custom_vendor/custom_theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/searchlist.phtml**
if you change in your overridden template file than you have to run three commands in order to get the proper output-

```
php bin/magento cache:clean  
php bin/magento cache:flush  
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```